# Count the number of rows from Remote Desktop Connection Navision

Tags: uipath

**Image from the Nav form:**
[image: Image from the Nav form].
Hello,
How would be the proper way to count
the rows in Navision form from Remote Desktop Connection.
UiPath recognize the RDP screen as image.
But the hard part is because there is something like more than 50 rows most of the time.
Every day different total rows.
They can be 10, 20 or more than 200.

Do you have any idea where I should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using [UiPath Remote Runtime](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/about-uipath-remote-runtime) to access RDP session natively, without the need to work with images. If you could install it then it's a simple data scraping excersise.

If your security considerations do not allow that your best best is using [AI Computer Vision](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/about-the-ai-computer-vision-activities-pack) which will recognize the screen content.

If that does not work for some reason you're in the land of OCR.
Here UiPath could help you with [IntelligentOCR](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/about-the-intelligentocr-activities-pack) and extractors but I am afraid that the only Flexicapture extractor does exactly what you need at the moment and it would require Abbyy Flexicapture license.

Alternative approach would include working with Navision via API or [extracting the table into Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav-app/about-export-data) (it is usully allowed)